# sequelize inserting ids as NULL with sqlite

Tags: mysql, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I am having an issue with sequelize when connecting to sqlite db.
whenever I try to insert something I get the following log and an error

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `table` (`id`,`address`) VALUES (NULL,$1);
```

it seems it's trying to insert a NULL id and that's causing an error, although it should log an error saying null ids not allowed since it's a primary key.

the error is simply : `Error`

my table definition is like follows :

```
{
id: {
            autoIncrement: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        address: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(256),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0
        },
}
```

and indexes set like follows :

```
indexes: [
            {
                name: "PRIMARY",
                unique: true,
                using: "BTREE",
                fields: [
                    { name: "id" },
                ]
            },
        ]
```

i don't see an issue with my table definition and when testing with a MySQL DB, this works perfectly. is there an additional configuration for sqlite that i missed ?

Comment: You don't insert a NULL into an auto increment column. You just don't specify it in the column list. So, you should only be specifying the address column and inserting just one value, not two.

Comment: I'm not familiar with sequelize, but if the properties that you used to define the column id map to the properties used by SQLite then your code should work fine. Open the database with a UI like DB Browser for SQLite and check the table's definition.

Comment: @forpas @ MatBailie, yeah sorry it was another error completely i jumped quickly to the so question. it's fixed now.

Comment: You didn't specofy `defaultValue` option for the primary key value.  Can Sqlite generate a primary key value automatically?